# query convert into laravel format

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need this query to convert into laravel format

```
select `likes`.`profile_id` as `id`, `assets`.`processed` as `processed`,
       `assets`.`id` as `asst_id`,
       `assets`.`profile_id` as `profile_id`,
       `assets`.`name` as `assets_name`,
       `assets`.`asset_type` as `asset_type`,
       COUNT(assets_id) as cass from likes
left join `assets` on `assets`.`id` = `likes`.`assets_id`
left join `assets_data` on `assets_data`.`asset_id` = `assets`.`id` 
left join `profiles` on `assets`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`id`
where `assets`.`asset_type` = 'V'
and `assets`.`access` = 'PUB'
group by `likes`.`assets_id`
order by `cass` desc
```

I am trying this query but its not retrieve the data but above query working fine

```
$dataaa=  DB::table('likes')->select('likes.profile_id as id','profiles.name as pro_name','assets_data.thumb_img as thumb_img','assets.processed as processed','assets.id as asst_id','assets.profile_id as profile_id','assets.name as assets_name','assets.asset_type as asset_type','assets_data.path as assets_path', DB::raw('COUNT(likes.assets_id) as cass'))
              ->leftJoin('assets', 'assets.id', '=', 'likes.assets_id')
              ->leftJoin('assets_data', 'assets_data.asset_id', '=', 'assets.id')
              ->leftJoin('profiles', 'assets.profile_id', '=', 'profiles.id')
              ->where("assets.asset_type",'=',$like_type)
              ->where (`assets`.`asset_type`, '=', 'V')
              ->where ('assets.access','=','PUB')
            ->groupBy('likes.assets_id')
            ->orderBy('cass', 'desc')
            ->take($take)
            ->get();
```

when i debugging the query. laravel generate this query

```
        select `likes`.`profile_id` as `id`, `profiles`.`name` as `pro_name`, `assets_data`.`thumb_img` as `thumb_img`, `assets`.`processed` as `processed`, `assets`.`id` as `asst_id`, `assets`.`profile_id` as `profile_id`, `assets`.`name` as `assets_name`, `assets`.`asset_type` as `asset_type`, `assets_data`.`path` as `assets_path`,
     COUNT(likes.assets_id) as cass from `likes`
     left join `assets` on `assets`.`id` = `likes`.`assets_id`
     left join `assets_data` on `assets_data`.`asset_id` = `assets`.`id`
     left join `profiles` on `assets`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`id`
 where `assets`.`asset_type` = V
 and `assets`.`access` = PUB
 group by `likes`.`assets_id`
 order by `cass` desc limit 8
```

Comment: Can you see what is query is generated using above code using Laravel debugger?

Comment: `->where('profiles.profile_type','=','T')` this was not included in the first query.

Comment: @ajreal i have update my answer. but this is not an issue..

Comment: `->orderBy('count', 'desc')` it should be `->orderBy('cass', 'desc')` ? `count` is not a column. You should just get the full query from Laravel.

Comment: If your raw sql works fine, then execute raw sql directly in laravel

Comment: @ajreal thans your response. but this is not solve my problem..

Comment: @NazmulHasan ok. i will try and i will update you

Comment: @ajreal any alternative way to execute above query (simple mysql query)

Comment: @NazmulHasan any alternative way to execute above query (simple mysql query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute raw sql directly if your raw sql works fine

```
$sql = "select `likes`.`profile_id` as `id`, `assets`.`processed` as `processed`,
       `assets`.`id` as `asst_id`,
       `assets`.`profile_id` as `profile_id`,
       `assets`.`name` as `assets_name`,
       `assets`.`asset_type` as `asset_type`,
       COUNT(assets_id) as cass from likes
left join `assets` on `assets`.`id` = `likes`.`assets_id`
left join `assets_data` on `assets_data`.`asset_id` = `assets`.`id` 
left join `profiles` on `assets`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`id`
where `assets`.`asset_type` = 'V'
and `assets`.`access` = 'PUB'
group by `likes`.`assets_id`
order by `cass` desc";

$result = DB::select($sql);
```

Comment: thanks... its work.. but i don't know why laravel format query not retrieve data from DB